# Where is Oulu Impijats/Impitaja/Impijas Finland?

Tags: 1900s-decade, finland

My great grandmother arrived in Quebec on 5 Jul 1907 from Finland.

The ships card showed that she was from Oulu Impijas Finland.

Does anyone know what parish to look for her baptism record in?

[image: Hilja Kaan Ship Record]

I got this record from the Family Search site under
[Vermont, St. Albans Canadian Border Crossings, 1895-1954](https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/3:1:3QS7-99D3-TQCH-V?mode=g&i=4833&wc=3KM4-2NL%3A1018494101%2C1018705301%3Fcc%3D2185163&cc=2185163)

In the same set of records, is the [ships records](https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/3:1:3QS7-99D9-CB9P?mode=g&i=58&wc=3KM7-7M7%3A1018492201%2C1018535101%3Fcc%3D2185163&cc=2185163), and it also shows Oulu, Impijas, Finland

[image]

I have looked but not yet found her sister, Anna Niemi.

Comment: Sorry I don't know much about the Finnish language but the most similar parish to what you have written seems to be: https://familysearch.org/learn/wiki/en/Impilahti_parish,_Finland_Genealogy

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [tour]. I have read a few more details from the card and added them to your question but I think it would help if you used the [edit] button beneath it to add some more.

Comment: What record group does this card come from?  Is this the only source you have so far with this information?  Looking for the records of her sister or other relatives, or finding the ship's passenger list could give you more variants of the place name.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The place is Ii - one of the shortest place names in Finland! Therefore it was often expressed more clearly as "Iin pitäjä(s)" which means roughly "Ii's parish" or "Ii's socken" (see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socken).

It is easy to imagine that "Iin pitäjä" would transform to "Inpitaja" or Impitaja". The other forms "Impijas" etc. seem to be shortened from that.

Hilja Katariina Kaan was born in Ii on August 14, 1889. Her parents were worker Kaarle Kaan (born 10 Nov 1860 in Ii) and his wife Priita Liisa (Brita Lisa) Kokko (born 26 Sep 1850 in Ii).

The baptism and other records for Ii are available at the FFHA (Finland's Family History Association) site http://www.sukuhistoria.fi/sshy/index_eng.htm freely up to 1887, the later records (post 1887) required paid subscription. Note that Familysearch.org has records only up to about 1860.

Comment: Thank you. That works for sure. I have looked the ones up that I can and get a subscription as I move forward. Now will see if I can find them in the rippikirja books.

Answer (score 3):

The city of [Oulu Finland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oulu) is located in [Northern Finland](https://www.google.com/maps/place/90100+Oulu,+Finland/@65.0126141,25.4626764,15z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x468032a8c02185c1:0x8bb02d322b12e97d) within the region of Northern Ostrobothnia, Finland.

[image]

I searched modern names of the different areas looking for "Impijats" "Impitaja", "Impijas" or something similar in different areas of the city, lakes, rivers and was not able to locate it browsing Google Maps of the city itself or the surrounding communities. I did note that most locations in the central city are prefaced with "Oulu" so that may help or it may just be a coincidence.

I did not see anything closely related to in the [list of Parishes listed on FamilySearch for Oulu, Finland](https://familysearch.org/learn/wiki/en/Oulu_County,_Finland#Districts). The wikipedia page for the city also has some churches listed on it but none match the name or seem close to the hand writing.

The place is also not listed in the Parish maps of [Finland on RootsWeb](http://robbsroots.com/fiparish.htm).

Nor reviewing the list of all modern street names of the city using [GeoPostCodes.com](http://www.geopostcodes.com/Oulu?loc=Oulu) but that is a place you could further look for further variations / pronunciation of Impijas or the name behind Oulu.

There is a possibility that the word behind the location of Oulu is not a location but an accompanying descriptor as well; but I do not know Finnish.

Comment: Oulu is also the name of the (former) county.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I did a lot of google searching and found nothing either. I do not know Finnish either, thus the question. This may be a place rather than a town like a farm or some other location in the Oulu area. I am just not sure.

Comment: @TimothyWahl The SE method of saying thanks is to to Up vote any / all answers that were of use and accept any answer that answers your question, such as if you feel Kari's answer answers your question be sure to accept it so they get rewarded in reputation points.